# GPU acceleration on WSL2

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, opengl

I'm running a cinnamon-session on Ubuntu on Windows Subsystem for Linux using VcXsrv, but I'm not able to get it to use my graphics card. (My Windows and Linux are running on the same computer.)

When I boot up I get a pop-up saying "Your system is currently running without video hardware acceleration."

If I set `LIBIGL_ALWAYS_ENABLED=1` then the programs I am trying to run are unable to use a version of OpenGL above 1.4, so the programs won't start.

If I do not use that flag then my programs run, but hardware acceleration (i.e. the GPU) isn't used.

Should I enable the flag and work on the problems there or disable the flag and work on those problems?

Comment: Microsoft has to make this available. Probably not yet. refs: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/wsl-2-post-build-faq/ , https://devblogs.microsoft.com/directx/directx-heart-linux/comment-page-3/#opengl-opencl-vulkan . btw the title is misleading. It's DirectX on WSL2, not directx on Linux.

Comment: @A.B ok thanks. I've found this other guide which uses a development build of Windows to get it to work: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/wsl-user-guide/index.html Haven't tried it tho